# Deleting a Pinterest pin via Pinterest API in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, api, pinterest

Apparently the Pinterest iOS SDK does not have a direct command to execute this function. How would one use the generic Pinterest API Endpoint DELETE for achieving this in Objective C?

I was trying to look at examples online to implement a DELETE call to the Restful Pinterest API (e.g. http://www.stlplace.com/2014/09/03/calling-restful-post-put-and-delete-methods-in-afnetworking-2-0/ and https://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial) but so far I haven't found a definitive solution. Does anybody have implemented something like that?

Comment: What doesn't work for you?
You can try pasting some code or error message to show how is your current solution and what error do you face

Comment: I was trying to build up a DELETE request from scratch, either using NSURLSession or AFNetworking. But then I found that the Pinterest iOS SDK has indeed a convenience method that is however not described in their documentation. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the Pinterest iOS SDK does have a convenience method for deleting a pin. It is just not included in pin section of the documentation at this point... (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/).

Just found this by typing randomly after [PDKClient sharedInstance]:

```
 [[PDKClient sharedInstance] deletePin:(NSString *) 
      withSuccess:^(PDKResponseObject *responseObject) {
           <#code#>
      } andFailure:^(NSError *error) {
           <#code#>
      }];
```